# WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally with make docker-run command

Tags: python, selenium, docker, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Goal:

Build Docker container to upload selenium web scraper to AWS Lambda using this page as a guide https://robertorocha.info/setting-up-a-selenium-web-scraper-on-aws-lambda-with-python/.

Currently testing local Lambda environment with `make docker-run` command that outputs the error below:

```
{"errorType":"WebDriverException","errorMessage":"Message: unknown error:
Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally\n  (chrome not reachable)\n (The
process started from chrome location /var/task/bin/headless-chromium is no
longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has
crashed.)\n","stackTrace":["  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/imp.py\", line
234, in load_module\n    return load_source(name, filename, file)\n"," 
File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/imp.py\", line 171, in load_source\n   
module = _load(spec)\n","  File \"\u003cfrozen
importlib._bootstrap\u003e\", line 696, in _load\n","  File \"\u003cfrozen
importlib._bootstrap\u003e\", line 677, in _load_unlocked\n","  File
\"\u003cfrozen importlib._bootstrap_external\u003e\", line 728, in
exec_module\n","  File \"\u003cfrozen importlib._bootstrap\u003e\", line
219, in _call_with_frames_removed\n","  File
\"/var/task/src/lambda_function.py\", line 150, in \u003cmodule\u003e\n   
lambda_handler()\n","  File \"/var/task/src/lambda_function.py\", line 33,
in lambda_handler\n    driver =
webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.getcwd() + '/bin/chromedriver',
chrome_options=chrome_options)\n","  File
\"/var/task/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py\", line 81, in
__init__\n    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)\n","  File
\"/var/task/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py\", line 157, in
__init__\n    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)\n","  File
\"/var/task/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py\", line 252, in
start_session\n    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION,
parameters)\n","  File \"/var/task/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py\", line 321, in
execute\n    self.error_handler.check_response(response)\n","  File
\"/var/task/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py\", line 242, in
check_response\n    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)\n"]}
```

Versions:

chrome 79.0.3945.88

headless-chromium 1.0.0-55

python 3.7.1

from requirement.txt:

boto3==1.9.24

botocore==1.12.24

selenium==3.141

chromedriver-binary==79.0.3945.36 (https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/79.0.3945.36/chromedriver_linux64.zip)

beautifulsoup4==4.6.3

Chromedriver options from scraper script:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1280x1696')
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=/tmp/user-data')
chrome_options.add_argument('--hide-scrollbars')
chrome_options.add_argument('--enable-logging')
chrome_options.add_argument('--log-level=0')
chrome_options.add_argument('--v=99')
chrome_options.add_argument('--single-process')
chrome_options.add_argument('--data-path=/tmp/data-path')
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
chrome_options.add_argument('--homedir=/tmp')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disk-cache-dir=/tmp/cache-dir')
chrome_options.add_argument('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36')
chrome_options.binary_location = os.getcwd() + '/bin/headless-chromium'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.getcwd() + '/bin/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Related Makefile code:

```
    # Get chromedriver
    curl -SL https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/79.0.3945.36/chromedriver_linux64.zip > chromedriver.zip
    unzip chromedriver.zip -d bin/

    # Get Headless-chrome
    curl -SL https://github.com/adieuadieu/serverless-chrome/releases/download/v1.0.0-55/stable-headless-chromium-amazonlinux-2017-03.zip > headless-chromium.zip
    unzip headless-chromium.zip -d bin/
```

Related docker-compose.yml code (env variables):

```
# scraper path
PYTHONPATH=/var/task/src:/var/task/lib
# chromedriver and headless-chromium path
PATH=/var/task/bin
```

Attempts:

Downgraded chrome driver (v2.43) and selenium (3.14)

Downgraded chrome driver (v2.41) and selenium (3.141)

Comment: you want the linux chromedriver, not the mac one.

Comment: I replaced the mac chromedriver with the linux one but got the error above in my edited post. @pguardiario

Comment: Can you post also the output of the docker build?